# Build fails after updating cocoapods to 1.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I updated cocoapods today, deleted the Pods folder entirely and executed `pod install`.

When i am trying to build now, i receive the error in the attached image.[image]

My podfile looks the following:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'MyTarget' do

    pod '....'
end
```

I tried adding `#define LOG_OBJC_MAYBE(...)` to my pch file but it did not help. What might be the issue?

Comment: Has there been a change in the version of CocoaHTTPServer?